# Projectile Motion of Electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, projectile

I want to know what happens to an electron when fired in a projectile motion. I tried to apply the Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle, but I had no idea. Does it's range, and maximum height reached, and total time of flight differ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An interesting question in my opinion - mathematically at a homework level, but conceptually could clarify a few things. We obviously start with a Hamiltonian like $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}-eEx$ and describe it as a wave packet on in terms of mean position and momentum, aka Ehrenfest theorem. I vote to reopen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Electrons aren't little balls that can be shot through the air and modelled as projectiles.  They're *waves* (or, at the very least, the best model we currently have treats them as such).  The same is true of *all* particles in particle physics and QFT.  Projectile motion isn't something that happens to waves, and so it doesn't happen to quantum particles either - it's purely a macroscopic phenomenon.

Comment: I mean cathode ray tubes can show nice trajectories for electrons undergoing uniform acceleration, so the question is technically answerable classically. This can be done in simple undergrad physics labs and can yield a good determination of the electron charge to mass ratio.

Comment: I mean, yeah, we can model the electron as a solid object with a clear trajectory and, in some cases, that gives accurate enough predictions.  But the OP tagged the question with QED and mentioned the uncertainty principle, both of which imply they're interested in the quantum mechanical picture.

Comment: Oh of course, I didn't think your answer was unsatisfactory but perhaps can be expanded. But it is also up to the asker of course.